# Differences between Xming and ssh -x

Tags: linux, qt-creator, x11, putty, xming

I have been setting up Qt Creator to run on an embedded device (Odroid XU-4) for my work and I have been getting issues with initialising the application. when I call qtcreator, I get:

```
odroid@odroid:~$ failed to get the current screen resources
The X11 connection broke: Unsupported extension used (code 2)
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "localhost:12.0"
  after 6 requests (6 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

I checked Xming was active and after looking around on a few forums, I tried installing a VNC server and xrdp on the Odroid to solve the problem (no luck).

I then tried ssh'ing through a Ubuntu VM and I got a different error:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

I managed to fix this one using [this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83949/with-ssh-x11-forwarding-ssh-x-get-cant-open-display-trying-to-run-x-app) 
and adding '-Y' during the ssh handshake. I added X11UseLocalhost to the sshd_config file too, as this was not present.

```
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Qt Creator now works through SSH via Ubuntu, but Id ideally like to have it running through the puTTY/Xming setup.

Ive tried turning on the -ac option in Xming Configuration but I haven't had any luck.

What are the differences between Xming and ssh -X that could be causing the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Xming is an X11 Server. The application works as a client and connects to the server to present the graphical interface.
By default Linux OSs have X11 servers, in windows you must install a Server manually, Xming is one of the options.

The -X option in ssh opens a tunnel for X11 between the remote machine and your local machine.
With this option enabled ssh will open a socket in the remote machine that is able to receive X11 connections and tunnel them to your local machine.
The X11 client application running in the remote machine will connect to this socket and the ssh in your local machine will connect to Xming. In this way you get the connection between the X11 client and Server.

Having that said Xming and ssh -X are two entirely different details of an X11 end to end setup.